# does the htmlEncode method replace the need for an nvarchar sql datatype?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server

If i use the htmlEncode method on all strings before i write them to my database, will that remove the need to store string data as the nvarchar datatype?

ie. do all characters which do not exist in the varchar datatype have an encoding value that can be stored within the varchar datatype?

Comment: But it is not a good idea to encode string for HTML when saving to DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your SQL server is using Windows-1252 encoding for char and varchar.
If the character is not in Windows-1252 then it is stored as ? mark in char and varchar.

[Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)

test by inserting

```
values (nchar(10000)), ('?')
```

HtmlEncode(nchar(1000)) is nchar(1000) and if you store it in varchar it will be stored as ?.

So the direct answer to your question is yes there is an varchar encoded value for every Unicode (nvarchar).
But that does not mean that it will decode back to the original value.

Comment: Thanks for further expanding on your original answer